# Regex to match string with an optional part in the middle enclosed with spaces

Tags: regex, string

I have these strings:

```
/usr/bin/sudo argv sudo ssh
/usr/bin/sudo argv ssh
```

and I have to match both with the same expression. I mean, "sudo" string is an optional match which can exists or not.

I tried next regex but it does not work:

```
\S+ argv (?:sudo)? ssh
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `\S+ argv (?:sudo)? ssh` => `\S+ argv(?: sudo)? ssh`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I like `.*` better. It matches both strings, `sudo` is optional, and it's much more compact.

Comment: Oh... I forgot the whitespace. Thanks for your help guys. Sometimes someone is focused on something and the solution is some trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\S+ argv (?:sudo)? ssh` pattern requires two spaces between `argv` and `ssh` when there is no `sudo` in between. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pNK2HS/1).

You should move the space into the optional group:

```
\S+ argv(?: sudo)? ssh
\S+ argv (?:sudo )?ssh
```

Both will now require only 1 space between `argv` and `ssh` and ensure there is a match even if `sudo` is missing.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qIVDZZ/1)